# How does one inject providers into an entity from the typeorm database?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I need to get a ClientProxy in an entity, I do it with the help of a constructor, but at the end the variable is undefined

**Entity**

```
constructor(
    @Inject('NAME') private messageClient: ClientProxy
) {
    super();
}
```

if you disable the messageClient variable, it is equal to undefined. how to inject providers into an entity from the typeorm database?

Comment: Why do you want to inject something into an Entity?

Comment: I need messageClient.send to be sent from the entity

Comment: But why? Why tie business logic to your DAO?

Comment: in order to glue the properties, the properties are needed for further search by parameters

Comment: I don't understand why you're wanting to do this. It's pretty much considered an anti-pattern to add business logic to the DAO.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Can you just tell me if it is possible to do this, if so, how ?

Comment: Nest doesn't inject into entities at all. The TypeORM container isn't a part of Nest's DI container. You can set it manually yourself from a service, but you can't inject into it. Hence the other reason it's an anti-pattern

Comment: @JayMcDoniel and what would you recommend then ?

Comment: Like I've implied, do your business logic in the service. It's why I've been trying to figure out what you're trying to achieve. Why the DTO needs access to a ClientProxy, I have no clue. It really doesn't make sense in my opinion

Comment: and if it's not like without business logic ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask

Comment: I mean, is it impossible to pass clientproxy to an entity?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel To be more precise, I describe @AfterLoad() in entity and under it an asynchronous method in which I try to make messageClient. send

Comment: And I make a connection from an external entity to another in an external storage

Answer (score 1):

> is it impossible to pass clientproxy to an entity

No, like I mentioned, you *could* pass it from the service via some sort of setter.

> I describe `@AfterLoad()` in entity

You might want to make use of an [Entity Subscriber instead](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#subscribers) as that lives within the NestJS DI system.

---

Personally, I still suggest you do this in the service rather than tying the logic to your Data Access Object. DAOs should be pretty dumb in my opinion, and should really just exist for mappings of the database entity and the code. If you do continue to pursue this, like I said, look into the entity subscribers Nest does have for TypeORM. While you can't (and shouldn't) do injection into the Entity itself, as it's managed by TypeORM, you can work with the subscriber.